# Вставить картинку в html отчет unittest-а

Tags: html, python, юнит-тесты

Возможно ли вставить картинку (некоторой функции) в отчет unittest-а?

Для моей задачи очень полезно для отладки представить данные графически. Сейчас, в случае провала сравнения, по специальному флагу командной строки, я показываю окно pyplot-а. Однако, при автоматическом прогоне тестов эти картинки, понятно, никуда не попадут, а хотелось бы их увидеть.

Для форматирования вывода тестов я сейчас использую HTMLTestRunner, но готов рассмотреть и другие runer-ы, если это упростит поставленную задачу.

Comment: а что мешает не показывать картинку в окне (интерактивно) а просто сохранять её в файл (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)?

Comment: @strawdog  Тогда нужно вставить html-tag со ссылкой на картинку. Это возможно?

Answer (score 0):

В оригинальной структуре объектов unittest-а, не предусмотрен отдельный канал для текстовых сообщений. Все HTML-run-ы перехватывают вывод программы в стандартные потоки вывода и печатают соответствующий текст в HTML. Отдельным потоком вывода для форматированного текста никто не занимается. Т.е. легального способа добавить html-узел в отчет - нет.

Однако, выход есть: 
[nose](https://pypi.org/project/nose-htmloutput/), в отличии от других движков, не экранирует специальные символы в тексте отпечатанном внутри  тест-кейса, а просто помещает текст внутрь `<pre>...</pre>`. Таким образом, можно вставить картинку в отчет просто написав:

```
print( '<img src="{src}"/>'.format( src=path_to_svg ) )
```

Что, конечно, является эксплуатацией бага, но работает.